# How do I recover from an over fertilized yard

Tags: fertilizer, lawn-repair, landscaping

Last summer I decifded to create a lawn and brought in top soil and planted grass seed. After six weeks, I spread fertilizer and then my grass turned yellow. I didn't water as much as I think I should have and by the end of the summer, I had some very green streaky areas where it was obvious that water from the driveway was being directed down my sloping yard. I live in Alaska and there will be snow until late April or May. When spring finally arrives and the snow is gone I would like to be proactive in recovering the rest of the yard. Besides the obvious of adding some new seed and watering frequently, what else can I do? I'm wondering if adding lye or some other type of neutralizer would help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that a neutralizer will help.  You have excess and uneven distribution if nitrogen in your soil and lye won't neutralize that.  The only way to correct it is to even it out in some way or let the grass take up the nitrogen over time.  If the driveway drainage is creating the problem by washing over the yard I'd start by correcting that with a french drain or some other method.  Then I would do as you plan which is to put down more seed and water more frequently.  The streaks will even out over time.  I would also go easy on the fertilizer.  If you brought in good topsoil that will go a long way to helping you grow a nice looking lawn.  If and when you do fertilize I have had good luck using a whirlybird spreader set to half the recommended distribution rate and making one pass in a north/south direction and the other in an east/west.

Answer (score -1):

Check the pH and get it back to 7 with a base.

Answer (score -1):

Dont add nitrogen. Next time add white clover, they fix nitrogen from the sun and only get to be 2-6 inches high